# React Native Network Request Failed iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native

here's the code im trying to fetch

```
    fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=14.588693,121.028468&key=mykey')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log('ADDRESS GEOCODE is BACK!! => ' + JSON.stringify(responseJson));})
```

but it keeps sayings Network Request Failed
i've already added the

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>googleapis.com</key>
  <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

here's my info.plist
https://pastebin.com/Q314UvrP

**CONSOLE LOG:**

> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
>   TypeError: Network request failed
>   TypeError: Network request failed
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror [as _onerror] (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:26971:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:199775:18)
>       at XMLHttpRequest._this._onError (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:199416:15)
>       at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:3156:14)
>       at blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:3257:17
>       at blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:27873:21
>       at _callTimer (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:27762:9)
>       at _callImmediatesPass (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:27798:9)
>       at Object.callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:28017:14)
>       at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (blob:http://localhost:8081/55322fd4-9cf7-416d-be9f-ba5e74a70509:2558:16)

**XCODE LOG:**

> Task .<1> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x281a36160 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalDataTask .<1>"
>   ), NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL} [-1002]

Comment: Show us the failure logs.

Comment: here's the console error : https://pastebin.com/584QTUFC

here's the xcode log : https://pastebin.com/EgY5yLRB

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to turn on the `NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads` ?

```
 <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
 <true/>
```

Comment: Yes, although i found the issue. seems like one of my codes has // window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
// window.Blob = Blob; and it affected the fetch